# Using Google Analytics for Google business website

Tags: google-analytics, google-my-business, gtag.js

I am discovering Google Analytics. I have started a Google MyBusiness website in order to test it. I wonder if I have to include the code snippet gtag.js:

[image]

But I haven't seen anywhere where I could add it in the Google MyBusiness part:

[image]

Comment: As it indicates in the first screenshot, you should copy the snippet to each page of your source code right after the `<head>` tag. See [this](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs) for more.

Comment: Thanks for your insight @dan I really want to add the snipet but I don't find the code. Do you know where I can access the code of a website generated by google-my-business? Should I shift to something else?

Comment: Sorry, my French is a bit rusty so I was unaware that you used Google My Business to create your website. Most people here ask the same question in regards to a website they created themselves. It looks like you're not able to edit the source code or add the gtag.js snippet according to [this](https://support.google.com/business/thread/23997812/how-do-i-add-html-code-into-my-website-that-google-made-me-domain-is-business-site?hl=en) and [this](https://support.google.com/business/thread/53282899/i-need-to-link-my-website-to-google-analytics?hl=en).

Answer (score 1):

Last I checked the free Google Business Sites are not compatible with Google Analytics tracking